# How to get the range of graph in google line/area chart

Tags: javascript, angular, google-visualization

Is there any way to get the range of values in google line/area chart ie., the start and end index of graph where it is currently on view to send to API to get the next values of values.
For example I have a data point of length 20 points and i am a able to see 5 to 15 points on graph where 1 to 5 hide on left side and 15 to 20 hide on right side. 
My requirement now is when i do pan left i need the leftmost element time range to call API to fill the historic data, in the same way when i do pan right i need the right most element  time range to call API to get the next level of data.
For zoom in and zoom out I need both leftmost and right most element to call API within that range.
Anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple methods you can use...

**1)** if you want the min & max values from the data table...

> `getColumnRange(columnIndex)` - Returns an object with properties for `min` and `max`.

use above method on first data table column to get min & max of values on the x-axis, e.g.

```
var xAxisRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
```

---

**2)** if you want the min & max values of the chart's visible range...

first, get the chart's layout...

> `getChartLayoutInterface()` - Returns an object with info about the placement of the chart.

```
var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
```

then get the chart area bounds...

> `getChartAreaBoundingBox()` - Returns an object with properties for `left`, `top`, `width`, and `height` of the chart.

```
var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
```

then get the values of the chart's visible range using following method...

> `getHAxisValue(position)` - Returns the logical horizontal value at `position`.

```
var minValue = chartLayout.getHAxisValue(chartBounds.left);
var maxValue = chartLayout.getHAxisValue(chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width);
```

*note*: need to wait for the chart's `'ready'` event before using above methods...

---

see following working snippet with examples of both methods...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
  data.addRows([
    [0, 0],   [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9],
    [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
    [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
    [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
    [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
    [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
    [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
    [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
    [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
    [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
    [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
    [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
  ]);

  var xAxisRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
  console.log('min data table value: ' + xAxisRange.min);
  console.log('max data table value: ' + xAxisRange.max);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
  var options = {
    explorer: {actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']},
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    height: 400
  };

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', getZoom);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', getZoom);
  container.addEventListener('contextmenu', getZoom, false);

  function getZoom() {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var minVisible = chartLayout.getHAxisValue(chartBounds.left);
    var maxVisible = chartLayout.getHAxisValue(chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width);
    console.log('min visible range: ' + minVisible);
    console.log('max visible range: ' + maxVisible);
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. The ready event calls only once chart is ready but i need the min and max values of graph on each pan/zoom. Is it possible? if that is possible it will be a very great hepl to me.

Comment: sure, you could listen for more events, such as `'click'` and `'contextmenu'` (right-click) -- see changed snippet above...

Comment: you could also use a `MutationObserver` to detect zoom, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40422081/5090771) -- And [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745775/google-chart-looses-zoom-after-call-to-chart-draw/40748353#40748353) of re-drawing the chart at a specific zoom level...